# Can you create conditional plugs in elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to call a plug from the else part of an if-else statement.

I've tried calling `plug SpiderWeb.AdminAuth` but I get the `ArgumentError: cannot set attribute @plugs inside function/macro.`.

I've also tried `SpiderWeb.AdminAuth.call(conn)` but I get error `UndefinedFunctionError at GET /user/1: function SpiderWeb.AdminAuth.call/1 is undefined or private.`

I could alternatively rewrite the entire plug in the else part but this goes against DRY principle.

This is the user controller file:

```
defmodule SpiderWeb.UserController do
  use SpiderWeb, :controller

  alias Spider.Accounts
  plug :user_authenticate when action in [:index, :show]
  plug SpiderWeb.AdminAuth when action in [:index]

  ## Action parameters changed to ensure only current user has access or admin ##
  def action(conn, _) do
    args = [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user]
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), args)
  end

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Accounts.list_users
    render(conn, "index.html", users: users)
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) do
    if current_user.id == String.to_integer(id) do
      user = Accounts.get_user!(id)
      render(conn, "show.html", user: user)
    else
      SpiderWeb.AdminAuth.call(conn)
    end
  end
end
```

This is the Admin authentication plug:

```
defmodule SpiderWeb.AdminAuth do
    import Plug.Conn
    import Phoenix.Controller

    alias Spider.Accounts
    alias SpiderWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes

    def init(opts), do: opts

    def call(conn, _opts) do
        case Accounts.check_admin(conn.assigns.current_user) do
            {:ok, _} -> conn
            {:error, _} -> conn
                |> put_flash(:error, "You don't have access to that page")
                |> redirect(to: Routes.page_path(conn, :index))
                |> halt()
        end  
    end
end
```

My goal is to ensure that only the current authenticated user can access the show page (with their own id) OR an admin.

EDIT: *Other attempts*
I've also tried making a separate dummy function and trying to plug the plug into that:

```
...
  plug SpiderWeb.AdminAuth when action in [:index, :do_nothing]
...
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) do
    ...
    else
      do_nothing(conn)
    end
  end

  defp do_nothing(conn) do
  end
end
```

But instead I get a `RuntimeError at GET /user/1 : expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection, got: nil`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it almost right, you only forgot to pass the second argument to `call`!

A module plug is a module with two functions: `init/1` and `call/2`. In order to invoke any module plug dynamically, you need to invoke `init/1` with the default options and pass `call/2` with the connection as first argument and the result of calling `init/1` as second. This is the whole plug specification. :)

In other words, you can do this:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}, current_user) do
  if ... do
    ...
  else
    SpiderWeb.AdminAuth.call(conn, SpiderWeb.AdminAuth.init([]))
  end
end
```

But perhaps, the best option is for you to create a new Plug that "ensure that only the current authenticated user can access the show page (with their own id) OR an admin". This way you can reuse it and keep the authorization logic outside of the action.